# Tried wrapping it around class=row but still can't get the input form bar to be longer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to organize my header section. I would like the input bar and button to be col-md-8 and the about and contact buttons to be col-md-4. I'd like the input bar to be much bigger than the "submit feedback" button, that button should be about col-md-2.

Here is my current code. Please actually edit my codes then post the new version. That is easiest for me both to implement and learn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap For Beginners</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello World">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<style>

    .nav button {
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 10px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFeedback" placeholder="Have Feedback?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Feedback</button>
                    <button type="link" class="navpill pull-right"><a href="#"></a>About</button>
                    <button type="link" class="navpill pull-right"><a href="#"></a>Contact</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>Student</h1>
                <h1>Business</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p>By:</p>
            <p>For:</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rho9q0h9/5/) to show what I have currently written.

Comment: Try changing `<div class="col-lg-6">` to `<div class="col-lg-12">`

Comment: @henry Lee, Im sorry when I added a Fiddle/Answer I somehow neglected to notice the Boostrap CDN link included in your header. This has been rectified. Hopefully it will provide an accurate description of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @KyleT: Note that edits are approved by community moderators, not the post author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already talking about specific Bootstrap's grid sizes when discussing how large the `input` and `button`s should be, I think you should simply divide the `.row` into those columns, and use a `button` per column. If you add the class `.btn-block` it will take up 100% of the width of the column.

See this example (if you want I can apply it to your code):

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">Contact</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">About</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

I've added it to your code example below (and removed some unneeded classes such as `.form-inline`). Good luck with the rest of your work!

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">


        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFeedback" placeholder="Have Feedback?">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg">About</a>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Student</h1>
        <h1>Business</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <p>By:</p>
      <p>For:</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you add it to my code? That would help greatly.

Comment: I added btn-block to the submit button and it did span the full length, but I want the form to be longer, but full block but only about col-md-8 or so. How would i apply that solution to my question?